# CSS Flex - I have a list of items can need to make them horizontally scroll with overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have 3 items inside a div.

This its container needs to be 100% widget with a horizontal scroll bar.

So like a carousel.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='item'></div>

    <div class='item'></div>

    <div class='item'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Outcome:** I want the items to go horizontal with a scroll bar.

Currently the above code breaks my flex layout.
I can do this easily without flex but I'm looking for a flex solution.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. In your code, there's no overflow because the items fit comfortably inside the containers. https://jsfiddle.net/L46qasdu/

Comment: its dynamic so they can have 10 items for example.

Comment: There are two flex containers. Which one gets the overflow?

Comment: See the answer below - that works.

Comment: `.content`: https://jsfiddle.net/L46qasdu/1/

Comment: `.wrapper`: https://jsfiddle.net/L46qasdu/2/ (notice how it overflows `.content` (red dashed border))

Comment: how would that work dynamically ? eg if sometimes theirs 5 items and sometimes their 10? because the  flex: 0 0 500px would be an issue?

Comment: @AngularM Updated my answer regarding the overflowed `content`

Answer (score 1):

A flex item's `flex-shrink` defaults to `1`, which allow it to shrink, and since your `item`'s as well doesn't have any content keeping them at a certain width, they will.

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `item`'s rule, and they won't.

*Btw, since the `flex: 1 1 0;` set on `wrapper`, and being a "flex item" property, will only apply to the `wrapper` if its parent as well has `display: flex`.*

---

Updated

If you make the `content` display `inline-flex`, you avoid the overflow of it, as an *inline* element grows with its content.

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 2px dotted black;
}

.item {
  height: 160px;
  width: 250px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='item'></div>

    <div class='item'></div>

    <div class='item'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see your carousel works in stackoverflow but this breaks the outside column layout